# Why is the field "contribution_id" in "civicrm_line_item" sometimes NULL

Tags: civicontribute

The table "civicrm_line_item" has a field called "contribution_id". For the most part, this field is filled in. But there are many records where the "contribution_id" field is NULL.  I have seen this with happen no matter what the "entity_table" value is.

Why is "contribution_id sometimes NULL? What would cause this? (I have seen this in version 4.5.x and version 4.6.5)

Comment: I've noticed this when importing participants/memberships. Could it be the same thing that you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

For every contribution, a line_item is being created. The `contribution_id` field is the FK reference to the `civicrm_contribution` table.

If I manually delete the Contribution record related to the Contact, the contribution gets deleted from `civicrm_contribution` table, which results in `contribution_id` to be NULL in `civicrm_line_item`.

Comment: I would have thought that if a contribution is deleted the line items linked to it should also been deleted.

Comment: @JoAnne - I believe the line items aren't deleted for auditing/bookkeeping reasons.  I could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one context where a `civicrm_line_item` record is created with `contribution_id` NULL:
[Line Items should be created for all Membership Signup/Renewal and Participant Registration transactions](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14918)

See also:
[Line item for membership entity should be created even when Record Payment is not checked](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15055)